# If $f : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous, then $f : (a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis

If $f : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous, then $f : (a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous

[This solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1568789/if-f-is-uniformly-continuous-on-a-b-is-f-uniformly-continuous-on-a-b) is for the reverse statement. Does the example in this still stand then as a counterexample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint

$f$ uniformly continuous at $(a,b)$

$\implies$

$\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)=L^+ $ and

$\lim_{x\to b^-}f(x)=L^-$ exist.

using sequential caracterisation of the limit and Cauchy criteria.

so, we can extend $f$ to $g$ defined on  $[a,b]$ by

$g(a)=L^+$  and  $g(b)=L^-$.

we prove that $g$ is uniformly continuous at $[a,b]$.

Comment: I see. I was under the impression it was False and I couldn't find a counterexample