# Are uniformly continuous functions on $(a,b)$ also uniformly continous on $[a,b]$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

I did my research on this question and I found two answers that I feel contradict one another: [this first one says it's not true](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1568789/if-f-is-uniformly-continuous-on-a-b-is-f-uniformly-continuous-on-a-b) and [this second one says it is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/178266/extending-continuous-and-uniformly-continuous-functions). When I asked my professor about it he said the following:

Let $f : (a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a uniformly continuous function. Then $f$ can be continuously extended to $[a,b]$

Then if $f : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function, then it is also uniformly continuous.

Therefore if $f : (a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a uniformly continuous function, this implies $f : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is also uniformly continuous.

I'm inclined to believe that the second and my professor are correct, but the example of the first one is pretty compelling.

Comment: You've got a good (+1) answer, but for posterity: If $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(a, b)$, (1) that does not mean $f$ is defined at all on $[a, b]$; (2) if $f$ _is_ defined on $[a, b]$ that does not mean $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$; (3) strictly speaking it's abuse of notation to call both functions $f$. A function comes equipped with a domain and a codomain. Changing the domain, for example, technically _changes the function_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$f$ can be extended to a  uniformly continuous function on $[a,b]$ but not every extension is uniformly continuous. In fact, not every extension is even continuous, as the example in that link shows.

There is a  unique **continuous** extension and this extension is uniformly continuous.